# malsup file upload page not sumitting as ajax format in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin

When i try to upload an image through ajaxsubmit function or ajax form function the form submit as ajax in Firefox, Chrome etc. but when submit the same in IE the values are sending in the format of html not in the mode of ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add_participant2').on('submit', function (e) {
        {
            $('#loadingmessage').show();
            e.preventDefault();
            flag = 2
            //alert('test');
            if (flag == 1) {
                $('#loadingmessage').hide();
                return false;
            } else {
                $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                    target: $(this).attr('action')
                });
                $('#loadingmessage').hide();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: There are 2 extra/redundant opening and closing brackets in your code.

Comment: I hope they are fine..